# Issue with producing multiline chart using WinRt toolkit

Tags: c#, charts, multiline

I need separate lines, but all my points, in all the lines are joined together for some reason. How do iterate through the series to get separate lines?
Here's my c# code:

```
    private void UpdateCharts()
    {
        double[,] Value = new double[,] { {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},{0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1} };

       List<NameValueItem> items = new List<NameValueItem>();

        LineSeries line;

        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            line = new LineSeries();

            line.Title = string.Format("Vg= [{0}]", j.ToString());

            this.LineChart.Series.Add(line);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                items.Add(new NameValueItem { Name = i, Value = Value[j, i]});
                ((LineSeries)this.LineChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
And here's the XAML code for the chart:

Using:  ((LineSeries)this.LineChart.Series[j]).ItemsSource = items; in the last line of my c# code breaks the program. It seems like a simple enough problem, but I can't fix it. I'm not an experienced programmer at all!

Comment: Shouldn't this line: ((LineSeries)this.LineChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items; be more like ((LineSeries)this.LineChart.Series[j]).ItemsSource = items; (notice the j in place of the 0). Also, that line should be outside the inner for loop, after all the items are already added.

Comment: Ron, thanks for looking at my problem. However, I tried iterating over j already. Somehow it's seeing my 2d array all as one series (the first series,0). So for instance, if I hard code my values as: Value = Value[0, i], Value = Value[1, i] and Value = Value[2, i], I can see each individual line. However, all these 'Values' in my items source are seen as one series, which is why all the points are connected. I need to know where i'm going wrong in defining the series such that I can iterate over it and get separate lines. I know it's a small fix, but I just don't know where i'm going wrong!